# How can i prevent focus on input?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Im trying to make `input` in angular-material2. How can i prevent `focus` on `input` if i press *visibility button*?

Here you can see how it works: [material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#prefix-amp-suffix)

Before pressing the button
[image: Before pressing the button]

After pressing the button
[image: After pressing the button]

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      #mPswd
      matInput
      type="password"
      placeholder="Ваш мастер-пароль"
      [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'"
    >
    <mat-icon
      class="unselectable"
      matSuffix
      (click)="hide = !hide"
    >
      {{hide ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}
    </mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) when you click the icon

```
// component.html
<mat-icon class="unselectable" matSuffix (click)="onIconClick($event)"></mat-icon>

// component.ts
onIconClick(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.hide = !this.hide;
}
```

Comment: (click)="onIconClick( **$** event)" and it works! Thank you!